# EC2: shared file system?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to access the same data across several EC2 instances. How do I get such a shared file system?

Can several instances use the same EBS?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, several instances cannot use the same EBS. You should do some research on network file systems.
2. The fact that your (virtualized) servers are hosted by Amazon is not relevant to your question.
3. Your question is not about programming. It does not belong on this site. You should rephrase it and search or ask at http://www.serverfault.com.